# Hide or collapse individual comments in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I spend a lot of time in SF chat. We like to post a lot of pictures in chat. They're usually not offensive or anything, and 90% of the time they're funny and relevant.

That said, there are times when it would be nice to be able to hide or collapse a chat message. Sometimes it's an image or an animated gif that's annoying/distracting, or sometimes there's text that isn't offensive, but I don't necessarily want it on my screen.

Can we have an option that allows individual messages to be hidden from view?

Comment: `90% of the time they're funny and relevant` That's what _you_ think...

Comment: You can stick something on the screen until it pass. => **10% not funny irreverent.**

Comment: This is definitely something I'd appreciate

Comment: The images don't actually bother me that much, but for devs at work or with bandwidth issues, I think it's a good idea if you could block images, so +1

Comment: What annoys me is those huge animated gifs

Comment: Potential workaround: use this to remove any crap from a webpage you'd like  http://kickassapp.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I made this simple script I use sometimes. It works for one-boxes, images, videos, animated gifs, crude language, etc.

### How to enable

You can run this code (at the bottom) either in the console of the browser or from the url with `javascript:`. I have it saved as a bookmarklet.

### Once enabled

*hover message for message actions*

This actually adds the functionality to hide a message inside of the message actions :D The message actions show up as a down arrow when you mouse over a message.

[image: Message Options]

*select "Click to hide this message"*

Note the top of the popout will now contain "Click to hide this message".
If clicked, it will collapse the current message and if there was a link it will no longer be clickable. Once hidden, the text in the popout will change to "Click to restore this message" and a click will return the message to its original condition.

[image: Click To Hide]

### Code

```
var popUp = function(a,e,f,b){
 b || $(".popup").remove();
 b={};
 a-=$(window).scrollLeft();
 e-=$(window).scrollTop();
 a < $(window).width() / 2 ? b.left= a : b.right = $(window).width() - a;
 e < $(window).height() / 2 ? b.top = e : b.bottom = $(window).height() - e;
 var c = div("popup").css(b).hide();
 $("<div class='btn-close'>X</div>").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".popup").fadeOut(200,function(){
   $(this).remove()
  })
 }).prependTo(c);
 c.appendTo( f || $("body") ).fadeIn(200);
  if( f !== undefined && f.hasClass("message") ){
  var hideMessage = document.createElement("div");
  var message;
  if( f[0].getAttribute("data-remove-message") == null){
   message = "Click to hide this message";
  }else{
   message = "Click to restore this message";
  }
  hideMessage.innerHTML = message;
  $(hideMessage).css("cursor","pointer");
  hideMessage.onclick=function(e){ shutter(e,c) };
  c.append(hideMessage);
 }
 c.close = function(){ c.fadeOut( 200, function(){c.remove()} ) };
 return c
};

function shutter(evnt,caller){
 var tar = evnt.target;
 var element = $(tar).closest('.message')[0];
 var message;
 var remove;
 if( element.getAttribute("data-remove-message") == null){
  message = "remove message?";
  remove = true;
 }else{
  message = "restore message?";
  remove = false;
 }
 if( remove ){
  element.setAttribute("data-remove-message","restore");
  element.setAttribute("data-previous-height",$(element).height());
  $(element).find('.content').fadeTo("fast",0.01);
  $(element).css('overflow','hidden');
  $(element).animate({height:'1.5em'}, "medium", function(){
   $(element).find('.content').css("position","absolute");
   $(element).find('.content').css('z-index','-1');
  });
  $(element).css("background-color","grey");
 }else{
  element.removeAttribute("data-remove-message");
  var h = element.getAttribute("data-previous-height") + "px";
  element.removeAttribute("data-previous-height");
  $(element).css("background-color","");
  $(element).animate({height:h}, "medium", function(){ 
   $(element).find('.content').css("position",""); 
   $(element).css("height","");
   $(element).css('overflow','');
  });
  $(element).find('.content').css("z-index","");
  $(element).find('.content').fadeTo("fast",1);
 }
 caller.fadeOut( 200, function(){caller.remove()} )
}
```

---

### Automatic Image Collapsing

And for all you avid chatters, there is an automated version. This version will automatically collapse any image or youtube posted as a one box (aside from ones you post yourself). Wiki, amazon, questions, feeds, and such will still work (perhaps those options will be in a future version if requested - it just seems that they are usually on topic).

*[automated collapse script](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpe28/)*

```
javascript:var popUp = function(a,e,f,b){   b || $(".popup").remove();   b={};   a-=$(window).scrollLeft();   e-=$(window).scrollTop();   a < $(window).width() / 2 ? b.left= a : b.right = $(window).width() - a;   e < $(window).height() / 2 ? b.top = e : b.bottom = $(window).height() - e;   var c = div("popup").css(b).hide();   $("<div class='btn-close'>X</div>").click(function(){   $(this).closest(".popup").fadeOut(200,function(){     $(this).remove() }) }).prependTo(c);     c.appendTo( f || $("body") ).fadeIn(200);     if( f !== undefined && f.hasClass("message") ){      var hideMessage = document.createElement("div");      var message;     if( f[0].getAttribute("data-remove-message") == null){          message = "Click to hide this message";      }else{          message = "Click to restore this message";      }      hideMessage.innerHTML = message;      $(hideMessage).css("cursor","pointer");      hideMessage.onclick=function(e){ shutter(e,c) };      c.append(hideMessage);     }     c.close = function(){ c.fadeOut( 200, function(){c.remove()} ) };     return c;  };  function shutter(evnt,caller){      var tar = evnt.target;      var el = $(tar).closest('.message')[0],          $el = $(el),         $c = $el.find('.content');     var message;      var remove;      if( el.getAttribute("data-remove-message") == null){          message = "remove message?";          remove = true;      }else{          message = "restore message?";          remove = false;      }           if( remove ){          el.setAttribute("data-remove-message","restore");         el.setAttribute("data-previous-height",$el.height());          $c.fadeTo("fast",0.01);          $el.css('overflow','hidden');          $el.animate({height:'1.5em'}, "medium", function(){              $c.css("position","absolute");              $c.css('z-index','-1');          });          $el.css("background-color","grey");      }else{          el.removeAttribute("data-remove-message");          var h = el.getAttribute("data-previous-height") + "px";         el.removeAttribute("data-previous-height");          $el.css("background-color","");          $el.animate({height:h}, "medium", function(){              $c.css("position","");              $el.css("height","");              $el.css('overflow','');          });          $c.css("z-index","");          $c.fadeTo("fast",1);      }      caller.fadeOut( 200, function(){caller.remove()} )  };  (function(){         var count = $('.message').length;       document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {         var n = $('.message').length;         if( n != count ){                 if( $('.content:last').find('.ob-image,.ob-youtube,.ob-xkcd').length > 0){                           var el = $('.message:last')[0],                     $el = $(el),                     $c = $el.find('.content');                           el.setAttribute("data-remove-message","restore");                           el.setAttribute("data-previous-height",$el.height());                           $c.fadeTo("fast",0.01);                           $el.css('overflow','hidden');                           $el.animate({height:'1.5em'}, "medium", function(){                                $c.css("position","absolute");                                $c.css('z-index','-1');                      });                           $el.css("background-color","grey");                     }            }            count = n;        }, false); })(); var sb = $('#sayit-button'), btn = sb.clone(false).attr('id','con').html('console').css('margin-left','5px');btn.insertAfter(sb); btn.click(function(){var t = $('#input').val();console.log(t);$('#input')[0].value = "";window.location = 'javascript:'+t;}); $("body").on("click","a[href$=history]",function(e){  e.preventDefault();  $.get(this.href,function(data){    var d = {     width:'60%',     height:'60%',     top:'20%',     left:'20%',     position:'fixed',     zIndex:9001,     backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',     borderRadius: '6px',     padding:'10px',     opacity:0.97    };    var div = $('<div>');    div.css(d).click(function(){this.remove();});    var cnt = $('<div>');    cnt.html($(data).find('#content').html());    cnt.click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()});    div.append(cnt);    $("body").append(div);  }); });
```

Comment: This shall henceforth be known as Traviscript.

Comment: This is really nice, I would like this to be integrated in the chat(s) by default. A useful option could be to auto-collapse all pics as SFW setting. Nice work Travis, as always!

Comment: Nice work Travis, as usual! I assume you couldn't make it auto-censor?

Comment: @CCInc - That feature is already present in the chat program. Simply click on a user's gravatar, and then select: "ignore this user (everywhere)" or "hide posts"

Comment: @TravisJ I am referring to the script cross-referencing with a "bad word dictionary" or something of the sort and automatically hide the post's that contain those words.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple stackapps that do hide images.  I suspect it wouldn't be hard to actually build a more integrated userscript.

- [Killit - Bookmarklet to replace single images from the page](https://stackapps.com/questions/3772/killit-bookmarklet-to-replace-single-images-from-the-page)
- [GIF Killer! Stop animated gifs in the Chat](https://stackapps.com/questions/3616/gif-killer-stop-animated-gifs-in-the-chat)

Answer (score 2):

I like Johan Larsson's solution, but if you're not fussy you can get the benefit of toggling without having to mess with the popup menus, which I find tedious. All in one line of jQuery (shown here as two lines due to width constraints).

`$('#chat').on('click','.messages',function(event){$(this).find('.message').toggle()});`

Yeah, it could be fancier, but this gets the job done. Note that consecutive messages by an individual will all be collapsed. But usually that's what I want anyway, if someone is spamming or whatever.

Comment: Only issue with this is that the post is hidden even if you click on the reply arrow as well.